# Want to track when a video is (25%, 50%, 75%) complete?

Tags: javascript, html, video, timer, tracking

Hey I use a custom built Html5 video player, I just wanted to know if I can track when the video has reached 25%, 50% and 75% complete. I was thinking of tracking the length(time) of the video and when it gets to the 3 key stages send an alert for testing purposes. So my question really would be is this the way to go or is there a better way to track if a html video has played 25%, 50% and 75% of the way through?

Comment: Ok fair enough. Forget the part about the custom player, how would I got about it if I was just using the video tags and the standard browser controls?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `HTML5` video capabilities, you could give a try to the `timeUpdate` event on media elements. Using jQuery:

```
$("#video").bind("timeUpdate", function() {
   ....
});
```

The W3C documentation is available [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#mediaevents).